# One specific htaccess line doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to lines in my .htaccess-file:

```
RewriteRule ^/backend/?$ index.backend.php
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/backend/?$ index.backend.php?vl=$1
```

The first doesn't work (website.com/backend)
The second works (website.com/en/backend or website.com/de/backend)

Why does the first line not work?

Comment: Try enter with end slash `website.com/backend/` or remove it from htaccess `^backend?$`

Comment: @Bora: `website.com/` is certainly defined earlyer in .htaccess and is used as prefix in the rewrite rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^backend/?$ index.backend.php
```

Comment: I don't work with PHP nor with RewriteRules, so I am asking this out of curiosity, isn't the `^` in the regex means start of line so how does it work with `website.com/backend` even though `backend` isn't at the start of the line ?